# packing a tcl program for deployment in linux

Tags: deployment, tcl

We are getting ready to deploy a Tcl application, but i'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. Currently, I'm experimenting with tclkit and sdx.kit. I can pack a single tcl file and run it, but the structure of the whole application contains folders and images and c files that work together with tcl. i have two folders and inside a bunch of c files and tcl files and other stuff. How would i go and wrap the whole thing. What tool do you guys recommend other than tclkit and why?

Answer (score 1):

The main way that you're recommended to distribute applications is as a tclkit. There are a few alternatives (e.g., TOBE, ActiveState's commercial tooling) but they're pretty similar as they all build on top of Tcl's virtual filesystem layer. (NB. This isn't the same as the Linux VFS stuff; this is a VFS in a single application.) Indeed, the ActiveState tooling actually *is* a rebadged tclkit (plus some other stuff like code obfuscation). I believe that TOBE uses ZIP archives instead of metakit databases.

The advantage of using a VFS-based solution is that it means that *lots* of things work inside, particularly including both `source` (for getting another .tcl file in) and `load` (for getting a binary library). In fact, you can put your application, the packages it depends on, and the resources (images, etc.) inside the VFS and be fairly sure that things will work. About the only things that we know run into real problems are where you want to `exec` something in the archive (the VFS mount is process-local; you have to copy the subsidiary file out if you want it to be seen in subprocesses) and if you're wanting to load certificates of private keys with the `tls` package (because the underlying OpenSSL library doesn't delegate to Tcl to handle that part of its I/O for some reason, AIUI).

When you're building these things, effectively you make a directory (and its subdirectories) that have everything laid out right. Then you run the packager (sdx for tclkits) and it builds the overall application for you. Attach the result to a runtime (the standard `tclkit`) and you're ready to test and deploy.

---

We don't generally do tool recommendations here on Stack Overflow, but the ActiveState Tcl Dev Kit is actually rather widely used. Many other people use `sdx`/`tclkit`. TOBE is quite a lot rarer. (There are other packaging techniques, but I wouldn't recommend them these days; a packaged VFS works very well indeed.)

Comment: thanks, i'm using vfs i just can't figure out how to point to the right folder, I had two folders common and tp, inside tp i have main.tcl how would i have to structure the folders in order to make it work. i try to pull out main.tcl outside the folder but i'm having trouble finding the rest of the files.